# How to know details of generating keying material in openssl library?

Tags: tls

I am testing my TLS 1.3 server (it does not use `openssl` library) using openssl `s_client` utility. I have found out that `s_client` can not decrypt `encrypted extensions` of the server. So I need to know parameters of decryption used by `s_client`.

Could you tell me:

1. How can I force `s_client` to output (if it is possible) keying material.
2. In which procedures/modules `s_client` generates keying material - IV, master key - I want to compare it with calculated by the server and understand the reason of differences.
3. In which procedures/modules `s_client` updates running hash during handshaking.

I am planning to trace `s_client` calls in (2) and (3) using debugger to understand the differences. Unfortunately, I couldn't find them myself due to large number of modules.

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-s_client.html#keylogfile-file

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank you for the link. This (-keylogfile) option allows to get the final result, but unfortunately does not output intermediate data (for example, used hash value of the handshake and others, mentioned in my question). If I would know where to see it in the debugger, I could detect where the openssl results differ from the result of my server.